# JQuery: .find() locates certain elements, but not others

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape glassdoor company reviews as an exercise, and I've attempted to learn javascript and JQuery to do it with `puppeteer`. In my script, I try to output to the console both the

1. Summary of the review, and
2. date of the review.

([Pictures 1 and 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bVuGS.jpg) for the html positions of the summary and date)

However, for some reason, only the summaries get printed to the console, whereas the dates are not. Do I have a mistake in my code?

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

// puppeteer usage as normal
puppeteer.launch({ headless: false }).then(async browser => {

  const page = await browser.newPage();

  const navigationPromise = page.waitForNavigation();

  await page.setViewport({ width: 1440, height: 794 })  ;
  await page.goto('https://www.glassdoor.com/Reviews/Grubhub-Reviews-E419089.htm');

  await navigationPromise;

  var data = [];

  const html = await page.content();
  const $ = cheerio.load(html);

  $(".hreview").each(function() {

    console.log("\nMain scraping function happening...")

    // This works
    console.log($(this).find("span.summary").text());
    // This does not work
    console.log($(this).find("time.date").text());

  });


  await browser.close();

})
```

Comment: Without your html code then it's hard to say what the problem is

Comment: Can you give us a sample of the HTML you try to scrape? It's likely that your selector is incorrect but it's hard to say without going to an external site. And a good question should be self-contained, so you don't need to visit external resources to understand it.

Comment: the dates are probably added via javascript

Comment: your page.goto might not execute javascript

Comment: Sample html code? I believe puppeteer is taking the html from the loaded url through `const html = await page.content();`.

At any rate, the link is to glassdoor, and the script only takes an instant to run, so I hope it's not too much of a problem.

Comment: @Coolio2654 if the HTML changes, then any answers given now would be worthless for future visitors. Hence why we want a self-contained questions.

Comment: I've uploaded two clear pictures of the html structure.

Comment: I browsed your given glassdoor link and executed the code $(".hreview").each(function() {....}); in the chrome console.It perfectly outputs the date.So definitely not a problem with jQuery find.You must verify does this element <time class="date subtle small"></time> exist in the loaded html.

Comment: Why would it not exist in the loaded html? Is there a way to avoid such a problem?

Comment: have you looked into the dom saved in your `html`variable? Is the date there under `.hreview`? if not, its loaded after actual pageload via javascript AFTER the pages html loaded initially, so you need to do a `waitForFunction` in puppeteer which evaluates to true AFTER the date has been set in the glassdoor site via js. see e.g. here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53483578/puppeteer-wait-for-all-javascript-is-executed that said, it would really be good to have a self-contained question, not with a reference to an external site, which could change.

Comment: Try console.log(html) and see if <time class="date subtle small"></time> element exists.

Comment: @Coolio2654 did it work out?

Comment: First off, running `console.log(html)` dumps seemingly the entire site's html content, and the date elements I was looking for *do* show up in there, which surprised me.

Running my script above a few more times after all this discussion, I noticed sometimes that the dates do get printed, and sometimes they are not, and I am thinking it might be related to what Dominik said with waiting for all of one's content to load first before scraping it. I will report back after incorporating his link's info into my script.