# Puppeteer with Chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js, puppeteer

I'm trying to generate a PDF using Puppeteer and insert there a Chart.js graph (but the whole PDF should be a text based - not a webpage screenshot). When I open the template I can see graph loaded, but in PDF there is just a blank space instead.
I'm generating it like this:

```js
async function generatePdf() {
  let data = { value: "myValue" };
  getTemplateHtml()
    .then(async (res) => {
      // Now we have the html code of our template in res object
      // you can check by logging it on console
      // console.log(res)
      console.log("Compiing the template with handlebars");
      const template = hb.compile(res, { strict: true });
      // we have compile our code with handlebars
      const result = template(data);
      // We can use this to add dyamic data to our handlebas template at run time from database or API as per need. you can read the official doc to learn more https://handlebarsjs.com/
      const html = result;
      // we are using headless mode
      const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ args: ["--no-sandbox"] });
      const page = await browser.newPage();
      // We set the page content as the generated html by handlebars
      await page.setContent(html);
      // We use pdf function to generate the pdf in the same folder as this file.
      await page.pdf({
        path: "output2.pdf",
        format: "A4",
        displayHeaderFooter: true,
        margin: {
          top: "2.5cm",
          right: "2.5cm",
          bottom: "2.5cm",
          left: "2.5cm",
        },
        headerTemplate: "<div></div>",
        footerTemplate:
          '<div style="width: 100%; font-size: 11px !important; overflow: auto; margin-left: 2.5cm; margin-right: 2.5cm; color: ghostwhite;"><span>TEST</span><a href="http://test.com" style="float: right; color: #1E90FF; text-decoration: none;">www.test.com</a></div>',
      });
      await browser.close();
      console.log("PDF Generated");
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error(err);
    });
}
generatePdf();
```

Thanks

Comment: Hi, if you have, can you please share the node js and html code of this, I am trying to do a similar thing, and couldn't figure it out. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to have Puppeteer wait for the Javascript to execute and render the graph.

You can supply a `waitUntil` option to `page.setContent` ([doc](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v1.20.0&show=api-pagesetcontenthtml-options)):

```
await page.setContent(reuslt, {
    waitUntil: ["load","networkidle0"]
});
```

Also, you should disable animation on your chart by setting `options.animation.duration` to 0.

You haven't shared your HTML/Javascript so I can't say for sure, but if your Javascript still isn't executed then you can use `waitForFunction` to wait until your graph has loaded.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53484341/219604) for details.

Comment: Completely forgot about the loading animations here. Thanks so much for this tip.

Comment: Thanks so much for the tip about the animations when it comes to printing!

Comment: `networkidle0` did the trick for me. Thanks a lot @ty.